# Get unique contact names from contacts provider?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am querying contacts content provider as shown below, it returns duplicate names of those contacts which have multiple contact numbers while I care for only Unique names despite number of contact numbers. 
I used:

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                    Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[] { Phone._ID,
                            Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                            Phone.NUMBER },
                    null, null,
                    null);
```

How to query for only Unique names?